# ASP.NET Core 7 MVC project Area folder empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-7.0

I just created an ASP.NET Core 7 MVC web project with local identity in Visual Studio 2022. Once I have done the migration of the database, now I can register/login, but I am surprised I can not find identity related code files in directory `Areas/Identity/Pages`.

I have attached a screenshot for better understanding. Can anyone tell me where those files are located? How is this even working?

[image: Screenshot of project]

[Full Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lnvN.png)

I have already tried to check hidden file but nothing exists. Any ideas?

Comment: I prefer to go to project folder and create folders physically then I add items .Probably those folders you see in this solution explorer aren't really physical folders

Comment: But how login system is working without those files?

Comment: RightClick on  "_ViesStart.html " class and select "Open Containing Folder" you should find files out there

Comment: No, I tried same. No file there related to identity @firatt_

Answer (score 2):

The source code for pages can be found at the github, for example the [Login.cshtml](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/UI/src/Areas/Identity/Pages/V5/Account/Login.cshtml) (or the account management in [`Account/Manage/Index.cshtml`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/UI/src/Areas/Identity/Pages/V5/Account/Manage/Index.cshtml)). From the code (see the usage of `IdentityDefaultUIAttribute` for example on [`LoginModel` in `Login.cshtml.cs`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/UI/src/Areas/Identity/Pages/V5/Account/Login.cshtml.cs)) and [.csproj file](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/UI/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.csproj) (see the `RazorGenerate` tags) it seems that the Razor templates are actually compiled and distributed as part of the assembly (you can view the C# classes with decompiler).